# How to make a new-defined alphabetic sort order in a locale work?

Tags: locale, sort

I'm working on a new Latin-based script for Persian. So I've used such lines in GB locale file, to modify the sort order:

First of all, I've introduced the new characters in such way:

`collating-symbol <acirc>`

Then, defined the order:

`reorder-after <a> <acirc>`

And, finally the unicode:

`reorder-after <U0041>
<U00C2> <acirc>;<CIR>;<CAP>;IGNORE % Â`

But, after I save the file, and run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, nothing is changed, and the applications such as Text Editor or LibreOffice Writer don't obbey the new-defined order.

**Should I do more to introduce this new sort order to apps?**

Comment: Are you using the locale where you added that? Does it work with simple, commandline UNIX tools like `sort`? LibreOffice does have the annoying tendency to ignore UNIX settings and suggest that users go use LibO's own regional settings instead.

Comment: Oh, of course I'm using it :D – I've changed number formats and weekdays too, and they work perfectly.
Also the commandline `sort` doesn't follow the custom order. Does it mean it's my fault in writing locale?

Comment: @njsg thanks dude! The `sort` command helped me. I just defined my custom order in en_US to make it work on Terminal.